# Ellispsis is not working despite everything i try

Tags: css, ellipsis

Ellipsis is not working and i'm loosing it.
Here is the CSS piece:

```
.inbox-widget-namecell {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 22px;
    top: 17px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 60%;
}
```

Here is the HTML piece:

```
 <div>
    <listbox model="@load(vm.inboxListModel)" zclass="inbox-widget-listbox" if="${vm.isEmpty}">
       <template name="model" var="item">
           <listitem zclass="inbox-widget-listitem" onClick="@command('handleClickEvent', currentItem=item)" >
               <listcell label="@load(item.folderNameCell)" zclass="inbox-widget-namecell"/>
               <listcell label="@load(item.senderEmailCell)" zclass="inbox-widget-emailcell"/>
               <listcell label="@load(item.modificationDateCell)" zclass="inbox-widget-datecell"/>
           </listitem>
       </template>
    </listbox>
 </div>
```

actual HTML
[image]

I have already tried:

- inline-block instead of block
- max-width instead of width
- pixels instead of percent

Any suggestions ? Thank you.

Comment: Please also provide an HTML sample…

Comment: Have you tried with some fixed width? In pixels let's say.

Comment: Yes i have tried this too.

Comment: That's not standard HTML. What's the actual HTML/DOM produced by this?

Comment: I'm working with Zkoss framework so this is the .zul file

Comment: Sure, whatever that is… *What's the actual DOM produced by this?*

Comment: Can you create an example of the actual HTML + CSS produced, demonstrating the issue somewhere like jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @trashr0x StackOverflow has an integrated Snippet functionality for this purpose…!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing "zclass" with "class" solved the ellipsis problem. (but caused other ones)